# Retrieving grandparent relationship from Trigger.Old in AfterDelete context

Tags: trigger, soql, triggercontext

I have a trigger on an object ('item'), which is a child of 'parent', which is in turn a child of 'grandparent'.

So a SOQL query involving `item.parent__r.grandparent__c` normally returns the ID of the related grandparent record.

My problem arises when working with an AfterDelete trigger context, because I can only work with trigger.old.

The record info pulled by the trigger is limited to the object itself, so `item.parent__r.grandparent__c` isn't accessible without querying.

**But**, I can't actually query that grandparent relationship since the record is now deleted:

`[SELECT ID, parent__r.grandparent__c FROM Item WHERE ID IN :trigger.Old]`

returns nothing, because there ARE no more Item records with that ID, because they are deleted at this point.

My current workaround is to build a list of parent IDs, since those values **are** included in trigger.old, then to query the grandparent IDs using a query on the parent object.

I'm wondering: is there a better way to get multi-level relationship info in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming the deleted record would be in the recycle bin, in which case all you need do is use `QueryAll` in your query. That will allow you to access the records that are in the recycle bin and have them included as part of your query.

Comment: Yep that did the trick!